# Out of memory exception when use gps in background

Tags: android

My app running in background via Service. It gets data like *latitude, longitude, batterystatus, speed, altitude and heading* every 2 min and push data every 3 min. I use a timer. But it throws *out of memory exception* when open any thing like camera, internet, music player etc..

Pls help I spend lot of time.
My Code is

```
package com.Multiplex.gpstracking;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import android.R.string;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.HttpStatus;
import org.apache.http.StatusLine;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.location.GpsSatellite;
import android.location.GpsStatus;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.os.Message;
import android.os.Messenger;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.text.format.DateFormat;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MyService extends Service implements SensorEventListener 
{
    int ll=1;
    // now get altitude,no of satelight and Heading variables

    int first_angel=0;
    Boolean  first_angel_flag=true;
    LocationManager   locationmanager;
    private SensorManager mSensorManager;
    private Sensor mCompass;
    public static int Satellites = 0;

    private static final String TAG = "MyService";
    String serverResponse="";

    DBAdapter db;
    String latLongString="";

    double ddlatitude=0.f;
    double ddlongitude =0.f;
    double ddaltitude=0.f;
    double ddspeed=0.f;


    InputStream xml_response=null;
    String imeiID="";
    String langitude="";
    String longitude="";
    String altitude=""; 
    String batteryStatus="0";
    String datetime="";
    String speed="0";
    String angle="0";

    int isGPRS=0;
    int isGPS=0;
    int  sync=0;
    int int_speed=0;


    String saved_id="";              
    String saved_imeiid="";      
    String saved_latitude="";        
    String saved_longitude="";      
    String saved_altitude="";       
    String saved_battery="";        
    String saved_time="";           
    String saved_angle="";         
    String saved_speed="";                                          
    String  saved_satelllite="";    
    String saved_gps="";            
    String saved_gprs ="";    

    String succes_error="";


    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0)
    {
        return null;
    }

    private BroadcastReceiver mBatInfoReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver(){
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent intent) {

            int level = intent.getIntExtra("level", 0);
            batteryStatus=String.valueOf(level);
        }
    };


    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {
        mSensorManager = (SensorManager)getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
        mCompass       = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION);


    }


    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) 
    {
        mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mCompass, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);

        timerOFRetriveData(5000,300000);        
        timerOFPussData(600000,600000);

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy()
    {
        mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
    }



    // The following method is required by the SensorEventListener interface;
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {    
    }

    // The following method is required by the SensorEventListener interface;
    // Hook this event to process updates;
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        float azimuth = Math.round(event.values[0]);
        // The other values provided are: 
        //  float pitch = event.values[1];
        //  float roll = event.values[2];

        if(first_angel_flag)
        {
            first_angel=(int)azimuth;
            first_angel_flag=false;
        }

        angle=Float.toString(azimuth);
        int int_azimuth=(int)azimuth;
        angle=String.valueOf(int_azimuth);

        int angle_change=int_azimuth-first_angel;

        angle_change=Math.abs(angle_change);



        int retval =Double.compare(1.39, ddspeed);

        //if(angle_change>90 && int_speed<5)
        if(angle_change>90 && retval<0)
        {

            getDatAfter_30Sec();
            PushData_afterInterval(600000);

        }

        else if(retval>0 && angle_change>30)
        {
            getDatAfter_30Sec();
            PushData_afterInterval(300000);


        }

    }

    public void getDatAfter_30Sec()
    {
        getBatteryStatus();
        IMEI();
        getUserLocationAndGPSstatus();
        GPRSAvalibilty();

        datetime=Config.currentTime();

        db=new DBAdapter(getBaseContext());
        db.open();
        long i=db.insertTitle(imeiID, langitude, longitude, altitude, batteryStatus, datetime,isGPS,isGPRS,sync,speed,angle,Satellites);
        System.out.println("value inserted "+i);
        db.close();

    }

    public void PushData_afterInterval(int time)
    {
        final int delayTime=time;

        db=new DBAdapter(getBaseContext());
        db.open();
        Cursor cc=db.getSearchRecord("0");
        if(cc.getCount()==0)
        {
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Data Found",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            cc.close();
            db.close();
        }       
        else
        {
            while(cc.moveToNext())
            {   
                saved_id                 =cc.getString(0);
                saved_imeiid             =cc.getString(1);
                saved_latitude           =cc.getString(2);
                saved_longitude          =cc.getString(3);
                saved_altitude           =cc.getString(4);
                saved_battery            =cc.getString(5);
                saved_time               =cc.getString(6);
                saved_angle              =cc.getString(7);
                saved_speed              =cc.getString(8);
                saved_satelllite         =cc.getString(9);                          
                saved_gps                =cc.getString(10);
                saved_gprs              =cc.getString(11);


                ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
                NetworkInfo info = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
                if (info != null && info.isConnectedOrConnecting())
                {
                    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() 
                    {
                        public void run() 
                        { 

                            try 
                            {
                                Thread.sleep(delayTime);
                                senddatatoserver(saved_id,saved_imeiid,saved_latitude,saved_longitude,saved_altitude,saved_battery,saved_time,saved_gps,saved_gprs,saved_angle,saved_speed,saved_satelllite);
                                 succes_error=parseServerResponse();

                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                //TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            } 
                        } 
                    }
                            );

                    thread.start();



                    if(succes_error.equalsIgnoreCase("SUCCESS"))
                    {
                        int id=Integer.parseInt(saved_id);
                        db=new DBAdapter(getBaseContext());
                        db.open();
                        db.updateRow(id,1);
                        db.close();

                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No InterNet Available  ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }

            }
            cc.close();
            db.close();
        }

    }

    // Will be called asynchronously be Android
    public void IMEI()
    {
        TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        imeiID = telephonyManager.getDeviceId();

    }

    public void getUserLocationAndGPSstatus()
    {
        locationmanager     =(LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        String provider     = locationmanager.GPS_PROVIDER;
        Location location   = locationmanager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
        boolean statusOfGPS = locationmanager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        if(statusOfGPS)
        {
            isGPS=1;
        }
        else
        {
            isGPS=0;
        }

        updatewithnewlocation(location);


        GpsStatus.Listener gpsStatusListener = new GpsStatus.Listener()
        {
            public void onGpsStatusChanged(int event) 
            {
                if (event == GpsStatus.GPS_EVENT_SATELLITE_STATUS || event == GpsStatus.GPS_EVENT_FIRST_FIX) {
                    GpsStatus status = locationmanager.getGpsStatus(null);
                    Iterable<GpsSatellite> sats = status.getSatellites();
                    // Check number of satellites in list to determine fix state
                    for (GpsSatellite sat : sats) {
                        //if(sat.usedInFix())
                        Satellites++;

                    }
                    Log.i("Setting Satellites from GpsStatusListener: " + Satellites,"***");
                    //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Setting Satellites from GpsStatusListener: " + Satellites, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    //satelite.setText(""+Satellites);
                }
            }
        };

        locationmanager.addGpsStatusListener(gpsStatusListener);




        final LocationListener locationlistener = new LocationListener() {
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                updatewithnewlocation(location);
            }
            public void onProviderDisabled(String provider){
                updatewithnewlocation(null);
            }
            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider){ }
            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status,
                    Bundle extras){ }
        };
        //locationmanager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 2000, 10, locationlistener);
        try 
        {
            locationmanager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 5000, 0, locationlistener);
        }

        catch(Exception e)
        {
            //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No provider found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    }
    private void updatewithnewlocation(Location location) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (location != null)
        {
            ddlatitude    = location.getLatitude();
            ddlongitude   = location.getLongitude();
            ddaltitude    = location.getAltitude();
            ddspeed       =location.getSpeed();

            langitude     =String.valueOf(ddlatitude);
            longitude     =String.valueOf(ddlongitude);
            altitude      =String.valueOf(ddaltitude);

            int_speed     =(int)ddspeed;
            speed         =String.valueOf(int_speed);

        System.out.println("******* lattiude "+langitude);
        System.out.println("******* longitude "+longitude);
        System.out.println("******* altitude "+altitude);
        System.out.println("******* speed "+int_speed);



        } else
        {
            langitude="0.0";
            longitude="0.0";
            altitude="0";
            latLongString = "No location found";
            int_speed=0;
        }

    }


    public void getBatteryStatus()
    {
        this.registerReceiver(this.mBatInfoReceiver,new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));

    }

    public void GPRSAvalibilty()
    {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo info = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (info != null && info.isConnectedOrConnecting())
        {
            isGPRS=1;
        }
        else
        {
            isGPRS=0;
        }
        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "isGPRS is "+isGPRS, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

    public void timerOFRetriveData(int delay_time,int interval_time)
    {
        Timer myTimerFirst = new Timer();
        myTimerFirst.scheduleAtFixedRate( new TimerTask()
        {       
            private Handler updateUI = new Handler(){
                @Override
                public void dispatchMessage(Message msg) 
                {
                    super.dispatchMessage(msg);


                    getBatteryStatus();
                    IMEI();
                    getUserLocationAndGPSstatus();
                    GPRSAvalibilty();
                    datetime=Config.currentTime();
                    System.out.println("Current time => "+datetime);

                    db=new DBAdapter(getBaseContext());
                    db.open();
                    //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Latitude is    "+langitude+" longitude is  "+longitude, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    long i=db.insertTitle(imeiID, langitude, longitude, altitude, batteryStatus, datetime,isGPS,isGPRS,sync,speed,angle,Satellites);
                    System.out.println("value inserted "+i);
                    //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "value inserted after 2 min  "+i, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    db.close();





                }               
            };
            public void run() { 
                try {
                    updateUI.sendEmptyMessage(0);
                } catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace(); }
            }
        }, delay_time,interval_time);

    }  // close timer  method


    public void timerOFPussData(int delaytime,int intervaltime)
    {


        Timer myTimerSecond = new Timer();
        myTimerSecond.scheduleAtFixedRate( new TimerTask()
        {       
            private Handler updateUI = new Handler(){
                @Override
                public void dispatchMessage(Message msg) 
                {
                    super.dispatchMessage(msg);

                    db=new DBAdapter(getBaseContext());
                    db.open();
                    Cursor c=db.getSearchRecord("0");
                    if(c.getCount()==0)
                    {
                        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Data Found",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        c.close();
                        db.close();
                    }       
                    else
                    {

                        while(c.moveToNext())
                        {   
                            saved_id                 =c.getString(0);
                            saved_imeiid         =c.getString(1);
                            saved_latitude       =c.getString(2);
                            saved_longitude      =c.getString(3);
                            saved_altitude       =c.getString(4);
                            saved_battery            =c.getString(5);
                            saved_time           =c.getString(6);
                            saved_angle          =c.getString(7);
                            saved_speed          =c.getString(8);                               
                            saved_satelllite     =c.getString(9);
                            saved_gps             =c.getString(10);
                            saved_gprs            =c.getString(11);


                            ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
                            NetworkInfo info = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
                            if (info != null && info.isConnectedOrConnecting())
                            {
                                Thread readthread = new Thread(new Runnable() 
                                { public void run() 
                                { 
                                    try 
                                    {
                                        senddatatoserver(saved_id,saved_imeiid,saved_latitude,saved_longitude,saved_altitude,saved_battery,saved_time,saved_gps,saved_gprs,saved_angle,saved_speed,saved_satelllite);
                                        succes_error=parseServerResponse();


                                    } catch (Exception e) {
                                        //TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    } 
                                } 
                                }
                                        );

                                readthread.start();


                                if(succes_error.equalsIgnoreCase("SUCCESS"))
                                {
                                    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Server succesfully accepted data "+ll, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    ll++;
                                    int id=Integer.parseInt(saved_id);
                                    db=new DBAdapter(getBaseContext());
                                    db.open();
                                    db.updateRow(id,1);
                                    db.close();

                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No InterNet Available  ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                            }

                        }
                        c.close();
                        db.close();
                    }

                }               
            };
            public void run() { 
                try {
                    updateUI.sendEmptyMessage(0);
                } catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace(); }
            }
        }, delaytime,intervaltime);


    } // close timer of pull data   method

    public void senddatatoserver(String saved_id,String saved_imeiid,String saved_latitude,String saved_longitude,String saved_altitude,String saved_battery,String saved_time,String saved_gps,String saved_gprs,String saved_angle,String saved_speed,String saved_satelllite)
    {
        try
        {
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            saved_time = saved_time.replace(" ", "%20");
            String url = Config.url+"imieno="+saved_imeiid+"&lat="+saved_latitude+"&longitude="+saved_longitude+"&altitude="+saved_altitude+"&speed="+saved_speed+"&angle="+saved_angle+"&cTime="+saved_time+"&nosat="+saved_satelllite+"&IsGPS="+saved_gps+"&IsGPRS="+saved_gprs;
            //url = url.replace(" ", "%20");

            System.out.println("complete url is  *****   "+url);
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

            HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet);
            StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
            if (statusLine.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                xml_response=entity.getContent();

                // do something with response 
            } else {
                // handle bad response
            }
        }

        catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {

        }
    }

    public String parseServerResponse()
    {
        String responseStr="";
        try 
        {               
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = db.parse(new InputSource(xml_response));
            doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

            NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("PushGPSDataResponse");

            for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {

                Node node = nodeList.item(i);

                Element fstElmnt = (Element) node;
                NodeList nameList = fstElmnt.getElementsByTagName("PushGPSDataResult");
                Element nameElement = (Element) nameList.item(0);
                nameList = nameElement.getChildNodes();

                responseStr =((Node) nameList.item(0)).getNodeValue();
                System.out.println("welcome  "+responseStr);
                //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), ""+responseStr , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            System.out.println("XML Pasing Excpetion = " + e);
        }
        return responseStr;
    }

}
```

Comment: Your service seems to eat up a lot of memory.  It is actually really large.

Comment: do you have a stacktrace or logcat for when the out of memory is thrown?

Answer (score 1):

Wild guess: `locationmanager.addGpsStatusListener(gpsStatusListener);` you ends up adding a lot of listener and never remove them..

My advice, refactor this, you should:

- avoid fields that can be local vars
- have a `DBSupport` class for DB access
- a `ServerSupport` for sending data to your server **(this could be a service)**
- etc

It will be easy to ensure everything is fine with more little components.